# Why do my Amazon Affiliate links redirect back to browser after opening Amazon app on mobile?

Tags: amazon-product-api, affiliate

When visitors on mobile visit my website and click on the Amazon affiliate link. If they have the Amazon App, I want them to be able to just buy it through the Amazon App.

Right now after clicking the affiliate link, it opens the mobile Amazon app and then redirects back to the browser and opens the  Amazon website. If they own the app, they don't buy it through the browser so I am losing money on the current logic.

If I go to other websites, when I click on the link, it just opens the product page within the mobile Amazon app.

What settings am I missing to be able to let my visitors use the Amazon mobile app?

As example, please check Business Insider

The Amazon link of the link below redirects from Amazon app back to browser
https://www.businessinsider.com/amazon-most-popular-books-all-time#heaven-is-for-real-by-todd-burpo-19

The Amazon link of the link below does not redirect back to browser and opens Amazon mobile app
https://www.businessinsider.com/amazon-most-popular-books-all-time#the-great-gatsby-by-f-scott-fitzgerald-20

I want the same logic as the Amazon link of the Great Gatsby book of the link above. How can I fix this problem?

**[UPDATE 1]**

It seems that if the book product page includes a kindle format, that the page redirects back to the browser. If it doesn't have a kindle format, the redirect does not happen. Is this a bug on Amazon's side?

**[UPDATE 2]**

I contacted Amazon Affiliate support center and they are now investigating if this is a bug

**[UPDATE 3]**

Answer from Amazon support center:

> the behavior you reported is specific to iOS and cannot be modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the behaviour is specific to IOS. I fixed it by not linking directly to the product page on IOS, but to the search page of the product.

Like this:
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=0099590085

I added the product ID as keyword param.
Now your affiliate link will work and when the user click on your affiliate link it will not redirect back to browser (if they have the Amazon app). Just it adds one unnecessary step for your user to have to click on the product, but this is still better than them getting redirected back to the browser.

If anyone has a better idea or if it got fixed, please let me know.